# Javascript function after a colon

Tags: javascript, event-handling, signalr

In the first example, only the ".click" is added whereas in the second example, in addition to the ".draggable" there also exists "drag:" right after

In Example2, why must "drag:" be added and what does it do? Would the code function the same without it?

```
    Example1: 
     $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                    $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                        // Call the Send method on the hub. 
                        chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                        // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment. 
                        $('#message').val('').focus();
                    });
                });
    
    Example2: 
     $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                    $shape.draggable({
                        drag: function () {
                            shapeModel = $shape.offset();
                            moveShapeHub.server.updateModel(shapeModel);
                        }
                    });
                });
```

Comment: don't paste code as image, rewrite it here in a proper block and you'll get an answer

Comment: You should probably run through a basic tutorial - what you're asking about is *object literal syntax*, which is going to be used extensively in any JavaScript codebase.

Comment: You need to refer to the documentation of `.click(…)` and `.draggable(…)` for that. Notice there's not just a bare `drag:` in the second snippet, the function argument is `{drag: …}`.